# Get multiple values with local storage

Tags: javascript

I'd like to retrieve the name and the date of created tasks. I managed to put the value taskMessage in local storage, but I don't know how to add taskName as well. This is the code I currently have :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var taskID = "task-" + i;

    $('.task-container').append("<li class='item-content' id='" + taskID + "'>" + localStorage.getItem(taskID) + "</li>");
}
$('.floating-button').on('click', function () {
    myApp.prompt('', 'Add Task', function (task) {
        if (task !== "") {
            myApp.prompt('', 'Choose time', function (time) {
                var d1 = new Date();
                d1.setHours(time, 0, 0, 0);
                var hour = d1.getHours();
                if (time > 0 && time < 25) {
                    var d2 = new Date();
                    var currenttime = d2.getHours();
                    if (time > currenttime) {
                        var taskID = "task-" + i;
                        var taskMessage = hour;
                        var taskName = task;
                        localStorage.setItem(taskID, taskMessage);
                        var newtask = '<li class="item-content ' + taskID + '"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title" >' + taskName + '</div><div class="item-after"> ' + taskMessage + ':00</div> </div></li>';
                        var taskitem = $('#' + taskID);
                        $('.task-container').append(newtask);
                    }
                    else {
                        myApp.addNotification({
                            message: 'Please choose a valide time period'
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    myApp.addNotification({
                        message: 'Please choose a value between 1 and 24'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            myApp.addNotification({
                message: 'Please enter a valid name'
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 8):

First you should get the data into a variable

```
var getData = 
{
   "firstData":"data1",
   "secondData":"data2",
   "thirdData": "data3"
}
```

Then you can set the above data's in localStorage...

```
localStorage.setItem('dataKey', JSON.stringify(getData ));
```

Then get....

```
var val = localStorage.getItem('dataKey');
```

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store two different values in `localStorage` then you can do somrthing like this **:**

- setItem in localStorage two times with different keys.

  ```
  localStorage.setItem("message", taskMessage);
  localStorage.setItem("name", taskName);
  ```
- Store both the values in an object.

  ```
  var obj = {
      "message": taskMessage,
      "name": taskName 
  }

  var val = localStorage.setItem("task", obj);
  ```

typeof `val`: string
Value of `val`: [object Object]
`setItem` method convert the `input` to a `string` before storing it.

**Try this :**

```
// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('task', JSON.stringify(obj));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var val = localStorage.getItem('obj');

console.log('retrievedValue: ', JSON.parse(val));
```

Comment: I don't really understand the last part. So how do I get the values from the object? Is it localStorage.getItem("taskID", obj(0)); for example?

Comment: to get the values : `var a = localStorage.setItem("task")` then you can access using `.` oprator. `a.message` & `a.name`

Comment: @FrederikDelaet Thanks for correcting me. I updated my answer please check i hope it will fulfill your expectation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out.

Comment: I am afraid I can't get it to work. It's the first time I am using local storage so it's a bit difficult. Currently I have this:                                 `var obj = {
    "message": taskMessage,
    "name": taskName 
}


localStorage.setItem('task', JSON.stringify(obj));                            
  var val = localStorage.getItem('obj');

console.log(taskName, JSON.parse(val));`

Answer (score 0):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) saves item key&value as `string`,so you call setItem with an object/json object,you must serialize json to string by `JSON.stringify()` method.when you get value you need parse string as json object using `JSON.parse()` method.

### Test

```
test(`can't retrieve json from localStorage if raw json data saved`, () => {
    localStorage.setItem('foo', {foo: 'bar'});

    expect(localStorage.getItem('foo')).toEqual('[object Object]');
});

test(`retrieve json value as string from localStorage`, () => {
    localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'}));

    let json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo'));

    expect(json.foo).toEqual('bar');
});

test(`key also be serialized`, () => {
    localStorage.setItem({foo: 'bar'}, 'value');

    expect(localStorage.getItem('[object Object]')).toEqual('value');
});

test('supports bracket access notation `[]`', () => {
    localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');


    expect(localStorage['foo']).toEqual('bar');
});

test('supports dot accessor notation `.`', () => {
    localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');


    expect(localStorage.foo).toEqual('bar');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store values in localstorage using following example.

```
//Save the values to Localstorage
localStorage.setItem('first','firstvalue');
localStorage.setItem('second','secondvalue');

//Retrieve the values from localstorage
localStorage.getItem('first')
//"firstvalue"
localStorage.getItem('second')
//"secondvalue"
```